# Make my Wit.ai-Bot response with random Strings

Tags: wit.ai

my Question is if I can get my Wit.ai-Bot to respond with a random response from an Array of responses?

For example:

User: Search for Cats

Bot: Ok. I'll search for that real quick.

...

User: Search for Cat Images

Bot: Sure. I'll look for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wit.ai handles the NLP. Once it knows what the user wants to do, you can use one of your defined 'Actions' to return a random response to the user.

Comment: Is there some kind of example of this in the docs or somewhere, so I can look into that?

Comment: The quick start example should help. https://wit.ai/docs/quickstart You'll need something like the getforecast action but instead of getting the forecast it would contain your random responses.